# Show data saved previously in Mysql database with implode

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo, implode

I need to know how can I show data saved in database and make actions about the treatment info.
I need to show the info like the first capture always...can you help me with these?

Here are the captures:

This one is when the treatment info are prepare to save into database:
[image: Treatment prepare to save into DB]

And this other is when the data are already in the database:
[image: treatments after saved into DB]

Here the code:

```
include_once("configs.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    try{
        $diente_id = is_array($_POST['diente_id']) ? implode(', ', $_POST['diente_id']) : $_POST['diente_id'];
        $cara = is_array($_POST['cara']) ? implode(', ', $_POST['cara']) : $_POST['cara'];
        $tratamiento = is_array($_POST['tratamiento']) ? implode(', ', $_POST['tratamiento']) : $_POST['tratamiento'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO ODONTOGRAMA (diente_id, cara, tratamiento, id_paciente) 
        VALUES (:diente_id, :cara, :tratamiento, :id_paciente)');   
        $stmt->bindParam(':diente_id', $diente_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cara', $cara);
        $stmt->bindParam(':tratamiento', $tratamiento);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_paciente', $_POST['id_paciente']);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'Registro ingresado correctamente.';                               
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The form in the page:

```
<form name="dentista" id="dentista" method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php $translate->__('Date'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php $translate->__('ID'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php $translate->__('Aplicar a'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php $translate->__('Treatment'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php $translate->__('Actions'); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>   
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_odont, diente_id, cara, tratamiento , DATE_FORMAT(f_odonto, '%d %M %Y') AS f_odonto FROM ODONTOGRAMA WHERE id_paciente=? order by id_odont DESC");
                    $sql->execute(array($_GET['id_paciente']));
                    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['f_odonto']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['diente_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['cara']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['tratamiento']; ?></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr><?php } ?>
            </tbody>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: tratamientosAplicados">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: diente.id" id="diente.id"></span><input type="hidden" name="diente_id[]" data-bind="value: diente.id" /></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: cara" id="cara"></span><input type="hidden" name="cara[]" data-bind="value: cara" /></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: tratamiento.nombre" id="tratamiento"></span><input type="hidden" name="tratamiento[]" data-bind="value: tratamiento.nombre" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.quitarTratamiento" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_paciente" value="<?php echo $id_paciente; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php $translate->__('Save Odontogram'); ?>" />
</form>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="img/ajax-loaders/loading4.gif" /></div>
```

The JS:

```
$("#dentista").submit(function(){
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"include/odonto.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(),
dataType:"text",
data:$(this).serialize(),
beforeSend:function(){
$("#loading").show();
},
success:function(response){
$("#loading").hide();
} 
})
return false;
});
```

And for last, how can I in the same ajax call make insert, update or delete some treatment or all?

Comment: the correct answer is that you are doing it all wrong. what you have there is clearly a one to many relationship, and thus should be storing the data in two separate table with a foreign key to link the treatment to the visit.

Comment: try looking at this http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/ for more information on the correct database relationship design.

Comment: ok I can do that, but how can I save five, six or more treatment info in the second DB with a single "click" in submit button... that I don't catch it...always save me the last one treatment and drop the previous...

Comment: firstly, it is not a second "db". it is just another table within the same database.

Comment: secondly, you do know that you can have multiple insert or update statements in the same php scripts, right?

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife well to be honest not...I thought that having more than one insert would overload the server requests... how can I do it...really need some help here because every tooth have seven procedures..for every face(front,back,left,right), on top, if took off or if the piece is not in the mouth..and for adults are 32 pieces and children 20....so there are 52 pieces in the odontogram with 52 pieces X 7 procedures = 364 procedures in total for every patient...and not to mention endodontics, periodontics, implants ... this is the basic odontogram. Best Regards!

Comment: database are designed to support insert statements. let them handle it. don't do too much premature optimizations. my policy is always get it working correct first, don't care about speed. then once it is working, then speed it up.

Comment: so first design your database correctly. make it at least 3nf. then write your codes around that. if its wrong, throw it away. Don't speed time plugging a sinking ship.

Comment: Hi @iWantSimpleLife, sorry for my late answer but I still have the issue...right now I am following your advice and I am working in a better code to save and show the odontogram...I also add better images into the odontogram(not just the squares) I am working with show the tooth and with JS show or disable if the tooth is not already in the mouth.. Best regards!